# Scala Spray Can: how to use a custom server pipeline?

Tags: scala, spray

I am starting a Spray-Can web server with "`IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(self)`"; it appears that the Spray server is hardcoded to use a default pipeline, which is all hidden away inside `IO(Http)`. I'm using Spray 1.3.0

There is a page in some Spray related documentation which [describes the server pipeline](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-M7/spray-io/pipelining/), and it even has a section about "Creating Pipeline Stages" (although it looks like).

However, if I create a custom pipeline stage, how can I get my Spray Can server to use it?

As far as I can see from the code, the server is hardcoded to use the default pipeline -- in [`spray.can.server.HttpListener` the private `pipelineStage` val](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.3/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/server/HttpListener.scala#L36) is set to a static call to [`HttpServerConnection.pipelineStage`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.3/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/server/HttpServerConnection.scala#L208), which allows no customisation of the standard pipeline setup.

My specific use-case is that I would like to turn on "requestChunkAggregation" for some URLs but not others.

I can override the pipeline with the "monkey patching" approach of defining classes with the same fully qualified names as the Spray internal classes in my codebase and then rely on the linker to load them first, but is there a less hacky way of customising the Spray Can pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Creating pipeline stages for HTTP clients are much simpler in Spray 1.2.1.  Here's how my team uses it:

```
val logRequest: HttpRequest => HttpRequest = { r => log.debug(r.toString); r }

val logResponse: HttpResponse => HttpResponse = { r => log.debug(r.toString); r }

private val defaultPipeline = defaultRequest ~> logRequest ~> sendReceive ~> logResponse 

def isServerOnline: Future[Boolean] = {
  val responseFuture = defaultPipeline(Get(properties.serverOnlineUrl))
  val serverOnline = responseFuture map { response =>
    response.status == StatusCodes.OK     
  }
  serverOnline
}
```

Comment: "simpler in Spray 1.2.1" -- simpler compared to what? I'm using Spray 1.3.0. "Here's how my team uses it" -- sorry, where does this code go? Please could you clarify the context? I'm starting a web server with "IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(self)"; how do I change the pipeline used inside IO(Http)?

Comment: You mentioned Spray-Can and linked to the 1.1-M7 documents, then asked a question about Spray-IO and 1.3.0.  I was misled by the first part and answered the wrong question.  My example is a simpler way of custom pipeline stages when using spray-can as an http client within the server (the server calls other internal services to handle the requests).

Comment: I think I don't understand all the different frameworks involved. I have clarified the question and linked to the actual version of the code which I am using. It is pretty obviously hardcoded to use a statically configured pipeline. I suppose the answer is pretty obviously "no" from that source code.